# SVG files appear to be render blocking

Tags: svg, optimization, frontend

I am working to optimize a website and trying to figure out how to prevent my svg files from render blocking. I am using the waterfall at gtmetrix.com and everything loads fairly fast with exception to a long list of svg files.

I tried lazy loading but that seems not to have any effect. I am wondering if there is a way to load these where they have no or little impact on page load speed?

This is a WordPress site and these particular svgs are icons in the navigation.

```
<img src="icon.svg" width="18px" height="18px" loading="lazy" class="">
```

[waterfall image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWakB.png)

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's not clear how you load/embed your svgs – `<img>` tag inlined svg or as `<use>` references.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How are the SVGs added to the HTML page?

Comment: @herrstrietzel Thanks for looking. I updated my post with the code example.

Comment: @chrwahl Updated with code example. Thanks for taking a look at it.

Comment: What img element shouldn't stop the browser from rendering the rest of the page. What is the file size? And I don't think that the loading attribute will help in this case if the image should appear at the top of the page (in the navigation). Something else must be causing this issue.

Comment: @chrwahl I added a picture of the waterfall showing that each image blocks for a while before it loads. They are loading one at a time. Is there a way to prevent this so I can get to my largest contentful paint sooner?